How to insert all Days in a Table for a selected Month?
I want to insert all days (startday to endday) in a Table for the selected month in a CalendarView.
So, I put a CalendarView and three Edit. And I have a Table named "Month" with a column named "Days".

EditMonth.Text := IntToStr(DaysInMonth(CalendarView1.Date));- which returns the number of the Month selected in the CalendarView.
EditStartDay.Text := DateToStr(STARTOFTHEMONTH(CalendarView1.Date)); - which returns the start day of the month.
EditEndDay.Text := DateToStr(ENDOFTHEMONTH(CalendarView1.Date));- which returns the end day of the month.


Now, I want to insert all dates between "01/10/2024" and "31/10/2024" in the Table "Month".
How can I do it using a loop or another way?

Since you already know how to get the start and end dates as TDateTime values, it is fairly trivial to loop between them.  TDateTime stores days as whole integers, so simply begin with the start date and add 1 for each day until you reach the end date, eg:
uses
  ..., DateUtils;

var
  dtSelectedDate, dtStartDate, dtEndDate, dtCurrentDate: TDateTime;
begin
  dtSelectedDate := DateOf(CalendarView1.Date);
  dtStartDate := StartOfTheMonth(dtSelectedDate);
  dtEndDate := EndOfTheMonth(dtSelectedDate);

  EditMonth.Text := IntToStr(DaysInMonth(dtSelectedDate));
  EditStartDay.Text := DateToStr(dtStartDate);
  EditEndDay.Text := DateToStr(dtEndDate);

  dtCurrentDate := dtStartDate;
  while dtCurrentDate <= dtEndDate do
  begin
    // insert dtCurrentDate into Table

    dtCurrentDate := dtCurrentDate + 1;
    // or:
    dtCurrentDate := IncDay(dtCurrentDate);
  end;
end;

On the other hand, since you also know how to get the number of days in a month, you can alternatively use a for loop instead, eg:
uses
  ..., DateUtils;

var
  dtSelectedDate, dtStartDate, dtCurrentDate: TDateTime;
  iNumDays, I: Integer;
begin
  dtSelectedDate := DateOf(CalendarView1.Date);
  iNumDays := DaysInMonth(dtSelectedDate);
  dtStartDate := StartOfTheMonth(dtSelectedDate);

  EditMonth.Text := IntToStr(iNumDays);
  EditStartDay.Text := DateToStr(dtStartDate);
  EditEndDay.Text := DateToStr(EndOfTheMonth(dtSelectedDate));

  dtCurrentDate := dtStartDate;
  for I := 1 to iNumDays do
  begin
    // insert dtCurrentDate into Table

    dtCurrentDate := dtCurrentDate + 1;
    // or:
    dtCurrentDate := IncDay(dtCurrentDate);
  end;
end;


I tried inserting in Table like this:
dtCurrentDate := dtStartDate;
while dtCurrentDate <= dtEndDate do
begin
// insert dtCurrentDate into Table
with Q1 do
begin
sql.Clear;
sql.Add('insert into Table_Month (Date) Values('+QuotedStr(dtCurrentDate))  ;
execsql;
end;
dtCurrentDate := dtCurrentDate + 1;
end;

@fatehdjelti That should have been posted as a new question, as it's not related to the loop issue. 1 question per post. But QuotedStr() takes a String not a TDateTime. You know how to convert a TDateTime into a String. Also, your SQL is malformed as you are missing the closing ) on the VALUES clause. Try this: sql.Add('insert into Table_Month (Date) Values('+QuotedStr(DateToStr(dtCurrentDate))+')'); If your DB supports parameterized queries, you should use that instead, eg: sql.Add('insert into Table_Month (Date) Values(:Date)'); paramByName('Date').AsDate := dtCurrentDate;

I also realized his mistake later. so my question was solved,  Thank you all

Glad you figured it out. Now you should read What should I do when someone answers my question?
